# clickable images in Raphaeljs

Tags: html, raphael

New to Raphael/JS and playing around with clikcable images. I am trying to display multiple images and based on which image is clicked to make it larger and the previously clicked image shorter.

I am using Raphael.js and the code snippet is like this.....

```
        var loc1 = paper.image("location.png",100, 160, 80, 80);
        var cont1 = paper.image("contacts_1.png", 50,150, 42,42);

        loc1.node.onclick = function() {
                clicked("location");

        }

        cont1.node.onclick = function() {
                clicked("contacts");

        }
        function clicked(img) {
            clicked = img;
            //alert("clicked "+clicked);
            //loc1.scale(.5,.5);
            if(clicked == "location") {
                loc1.animate({width: 80, height: 80}, 1000);
                cont1.animate({width: 42, height: 42}, 1000);

            }
            else if(clicked == "contacts") {
                loc1.animate({width: 42, height: 42}, 1000);
                cont1.animate({width: 80, height: 80}, 1000);


            }
       }
```

What am I doing wrong that the click is not working when I add cont1.node.onlcick? It works with just one onclick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much time to explain what's wrong with your code. But I recommend you to use the framework methods to deal with the objects you create inside of it.

In this particular case I think is better to use the Raphael's click method.

An example using your code follows

```
    var loc1 = paper.image("location.png", 100, 160, 80, 80);
    var cont1 = paper.image("contacts_1.png", 50,150, 42,42);


   loc1.click(function(){
         loc1.animate({width: 80, height: 80}, 1000);
         cont1.animate({width: 42, height: 42}, 1000);
   })

   cont1.click(function(){
            loc1.animate({width: 42, height: 42}, 1000);
            cont1.animate({width: 80, height: 80}, 1000);
   })
```

This way, you are assigning the function to the raphael object, and you don't need to use the `if` with the identifiers.